# How can I replace the root view in SwiftUI using the NavigationStack?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am currently playing with the new NavigationStack component in SwiftUI and I would like to recreate a scenario where the app remembers a user and when the user logs out of the app it goes back to a view that is not pushed into the stack.

I notice that the root view in the NavigationStack can not be programatically changed because when the array that holds the stack always starts empty when you add the NavigationStack in a view (the view that is currently visible). Is there a way to swap the root view?

Comment: Look into `SceneStorage`, I haven't tried it yet but the `path` mentioned in the videos should be able to be stored there. Remembering the user takes a lot more work and is not directly related to SwiftUI. It is impossible to help you solve that part with he information you have provided.

Comment: your question and description do not match at all

Comment: I just edited the question. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I realized that you can't replace the root view. According to Apple's documentation:

[image]

So if you want to change the root you need to do something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isLogged = false 
    // or you could use an observableObject to handle this state
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            if isLogged {
                LoggedView()
            } else {
                LoginView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario and I solved it by using [this package](https://github.com/matteopuc/swiftui-navigation-stack). You can forward users to a specific screen by using a screen id.

Comment: Link only answers aren’t allowed in SO. If there is relevant code in the link post it as an answer. Links break over time. When you have enough reputation you can post links as comments.

Comment: Your answer should be posted as comment because it contains no helpful demonstration.